# Eclipse Editor monitor file changes from out of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing a Plugin for eclipse, and notice that when user changes file from out of IDE, e.g., do a git pull using shell, my editor does not pick up the change. I try to use `IResourceChangeListener` but realize it only monitors changes happening in the workspace.

I have seen eclipse `TextEditor` can monitor external file change, but failed to find how it implements this from code. My editor is not a text editor so I cannot extend from `TextEditor` to get this for free.

Can anyone give me a hint how to properly implement this feature for eclipse? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Eclipse FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_react_to_changes_in_source_files%3F) you need to monitor non Eclipse file changes in separate thread.

Fortunately Java have [file change notification API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) which can be used to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for you hint! For sure I can start from scratch, but as Eclipse already have this feature in ``TextEditor``, I think there should be something I can reuse. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Take a look into https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/tree/master/org.eclipse.ui.editors/src/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor

Comment: This file https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/d68c3b21d24ab313e97359beeb42205bce4a31e7/org.eclipse.core.filebuffers/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/filebuffers/ResourceFileBuffer.java